# Infinite Loop when launching Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, coffeescript

Let me explain my isssue in steps and short example:

**Step 1:** creating new project:

```
rails new Project
```

**Step2:** creating a controler:

```
rails generate controller Pages home contact
```

**Step3:** launching my server:

```
rails s
```

**Step4:** request the url: localhost:8000/pages/home

An infinite loop of chars starts ! After a while it displays:

```
js: "/tmp/execjs20120131-2808-a2gs3e.js", line 508: il manque '}' après le corps d'une fonction
js: });
js: ..^
  (in /home/Projet/app/assets/javascripts/pages.js.coffee)):
3: <head>
4:   <title>ProjetTest2</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
9: <body>
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___588914926_92363960'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm weird, try `LC_ALL=C rails s` to see if this is locale specific. What Rails version is this? and could you post /tmp/execjs20120131-2808-a2gs3e.js?

Comment: @MattiasWadman: 1. Still get the same issue with:    LC_ALL=C rails s     
2. I'm using version 3.2.0 of rails
3. There is no file in /tmp, only 4 directories ! Thx for your quick respond

Comment: The obvious clue is line 6, `6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` so we need to see the JS you've added.  Could it be you've got a mistake in `pages.js.coffee`?

Comment: @MichaeldeSilva: I only did the 4 Steps, No JS have been added and  **pages.js.coffee** is empty. Thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution. I just installed nodejs:
`sudo apt-get install nodejs`

and the following gems: 
**therubyracer, execjs, mustang**

Comment: Good. But i guess that installing either the therubyracer gem, nodejs or the mustang gem (only one of them) was enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.0)
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > ExecJS::Runtimes.autodetect
 => #<ExecJS::ExternalRuntime:0x00000101100048 @name="JavaScriptCore", @command="/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/jsc", @runner_path="/Users/mattias/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/execjs-1.3.0/lib/execjs/support/jsc_runner.js", @test_args=nil, @test_match=nil, @encoding=nil, @binary="/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/jsc"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > CoffeeScript.compile(open("app/assets/javascripts/pages.js.coffee").read)
 => "(function() {\n\n\n\n}).call(this);\n" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 >
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, i get the infinite loop after typing **CoffeeScript.compile(open("app/assets/javascripts/pages.js.coffee").read)**
Please note that **pages.js.coffee** is empty

Comment: What does the backtrace looks like if you abort with ctrl-c? and what do you get if you run `ExecJS::Runtimes.autodetect` in the console?

Comment: Here is the first of the backtrace **/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails310/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:24:in `shutdown': undefined method `shutdown' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)**. 

The second command gives me this: **<ExecJS::ExternalRuntime:0x8a51e0c @name="SpiderMonkey", @command="js", @runner_path="/home/simo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails310/gems/execjs-1.3.0/lib/execjs/support/spidermonkey_runner.js", @test_args=nil, @test_match=nil, @encoding=nil, @binary="js">**

Comment: I meant the backtrace when it hangs in the console. Hmm it looks like you have two rvm installtions, maybe that messes things up. Try to start rails with `bundle exec rails server`.

Comment: `bundle exec rails server` gives the same error, i remove other rvm just to be sure that i'm using one, but still get the same issue

Comment: I really don't know whats going on but maybe you have an incompatible spider monkey version. You could try to install the [therubyracer gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/therubyracer) which seams to be the preferred JavaScript engine by Rails.